# PHP when md5 returns null value

Tags: php, ctf

I have a question.
So I was doing ctf and there was this if statement. I have no idea how to get past it.
`if(isset($_POST['var']) && md5($_POST['var']) == NULL)`
All I'm asking for is a little hint, thanks.

Comment: I don't think `md5()` ever returns NULL.

Comment: Type juggling also won't make them equal. Integer 0 is == NULL, but `md5()` returns a string. Only an empty string is == NULL, but `md5()` returns a 32-character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's a hint.

PHP's [md5()](https://www.php.net/md5) function expects its argument to be a string.

Can you think of some way of forcing this statement to deal with a different data type?

Comment: It worked! I have changed the post data from var to var[] so now it is an array. Also added var[]=1 so now it's set. Thanks.